# Getting Error : for React Native : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: react-native, libraries

I'm Getting this error on react-native while adding new libraries

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/exoplayer2/LoadControl.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I Got it why its returning error by running the following command in android folder

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Found exoplayer occurrence with multiple versions under different libraries.

I'm using `react-native-track-player` and `react-native-audio-streamer`

```
...
|    \--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.1.1
...


...
    |    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.3
...
```

When I removed `react-native-audio-streamer` and run `react-native run-android` Its working
How can I change the sub library version being not an owner of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
./gradlew clean
```

and then build it again